# How to run selenium server in the background using windows batch script in Jenkins?

Tags: windows, batch-file, selenium, jenkins, protractor

I am running protractor tests on a server machine through Jenkins. I need to start the selenium web driver before running the tests. i.e. "webdriver-manager start" and run the tests while the server is running and shut it down once tests are run. How do I do this using batch script?

I am using start, cmd commands in the batch file to achieve it but once the selenium server starts, I am unable to go back to the prompt unless I stop it.

How to I make it run in the background by staying in the same command prompt window rather than opening up the new command prompt window selenium server starts?

Answer (score 0):

you should run webdriver-manager start as shell script.

Make sure

1 - Node.js installed on jenkins

2 - provide correct path to webdriver-manager